# MySQL - How to optimize long running query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that takes a very long time to complete. I am wondering if there is anyway to optimize it so it would run quicker. Currently the table has around 15 million row and has indexing on expirationDate. This query has been running for 8000+ seconds.

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY items
SET    expire = 1
WHERE  expirationdate < Curdate()
       AND expirationdate != '000-00-00'
       AND expire = '0'
       AND ( `submit_id` != '742457'
              OR submit_id IS NULL )
```

Comment: If you need to update many rows (a significant percentage of the total), it might be faster to remove indexes and add them after the update. Otherwise, every update will cause an update of the indexes as well.

Comment: Out of the 15 million, how many records do you expect to need updating? All, half, or just a few thousand/hundred?

Comment: The problem is that it is a heavily utilized table and removing the indexes would severely impact the performance of our site.

Comment: I would say anywhere between 5000-30000 depending on the day of the week.

Comment: Are you sure it is not because there are locks on the table from other queries/transactions?

Comment: [LOW_PRIORITY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is going to wait for all reads to complete. You might also consider defaulting `expirationDate` to `NULL` and removing the `!= '0000-00-00'` condition.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis, if the update were waiting on locks, it would have timed out. Unless he set his `lock_wait_timeout` configuration variable higher than 8000 seconds (it is 50 seconds by default).

Comment: So @BillKarwin he is actually affecting rows in the 8000 seconds - I wonder how many in total for each of the queries..This doesn't seem normal - 15million is not that terrible if he is doing 10-50k updates

Comment: This does smell like a lock contention issue, especially since the table is heavily utilized.  As such, the update might run faster at a more lax [transaction isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html), such as `READ UNCOMMITTED`, though that is not without its own costs.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind your table structure (I requested it before this edit), I have a solution for you.  I've done this before with my DBAs several times on our production mySQL databases even during peak hours of the day.  The approach you need to take is taking your one massive UPDATE query (that will lock the table while executing) and turn it into several individual updates.  Those individual updates will not have a material impact on your database, especially if you run them in smaller batches and break it down.

To generate those individual queries, run this (assuming the items table's primary key is named "id"):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  ‘UPDATE items SET expire = 1 WHERE id = ‘, 
  items.id,
  ‘;’) AS ''
FROM items
WHERE expirationdate < Curdate()
AND expirationdate != '000-00-00'
AND expire = '0'
AND ( `submit_id` != ‘742457'
OR submit_id IS NULL )
```

This will generate SQL that looks like this:

```
UPDATE items SET expire = 1 WHERE id = 1234;
UPDATE items SET expire = 1 WHERE id = 2345;
.....
```

What I personally like to do is put the above query in a text file and run this from the command line:

```
cat theQuery.sql | mysql -u yourusername [+ command line args with db host, etc] -p > outputSQLCommands.sql
```

This will pass the query to mySQL and dump the results to an output file.  If you notice, we named the column in our output to '' (nothing).  That makes the output very nicely formatted in the text file so it can be easily dumped back into mySQL to run the commands.  In fact you could do it all in one fell swoop like this:

```
cat theQuery.sql | mysql -u yourusername [+ command line args with db host, etc] -p | mysql -u yourusername [+ command line args with db host, etc] -p
```

Then you are definitely ballin' SQL style.

After you have the output SQL file though, if it's too many queries to run one after another, you can use a command line tool like "split" to split the file into a bunch of smaller files.

I would recommend testing to find the optimum batch size based on your DB's hardware/performance/etc.  For example, try running 1000 updates first, if that works with no material impact try 5000, etc.  Then you can split the rest of your file into chunks you are comfortable with and run them through.

Good luck!